# Why selecting STUFF value decrease performance of a query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stuff

Recently I want to improve some of my queries and I see something that I don't really understand, here is my query :

```
SELECT   
    S.VENTE_GUID, Top6QtySold.list
FROM 
    SALES s with(nolock) 
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT 
         STUFF((SELECT TOP(6) ',' + t.CodeProd
                FROM topSold t 
                WHERE t.VENTE_GUID = s.SALE_GUID
                ORDER BY t.nbOrdered DESC
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS list
     ) AS Top6QtySold
```

When I execute this query, it takes around 6 seconds, but when I comment out the column: `op6QtySold.list` in the `SELECT` statement, it takes less than 1 second.

I know that the number of columns in the SELECT statement can decrease performance but in this case, the hard work has been done by the `OUTER APPLY` and it should be a formality to display the value of `Top6QtySold`, no ?

(I simplify the query but imagine that there is a lot of data in the SELECT part and more joins)

Comment: provide a sample of data to get better recommendation from community

Comment: Compare the execution plans of the queries.

Comment: When I compare the executions plans,  I see that when I comment on the `op6QtySold.list`, it's like SQL don't care about the `OUTER APPLY` and do nothing except search in the `SALES` table.

Comment: Exactlty, its nothing to do with STUFF, the thing slowing it down is the correlated subquery with TOP/ORDER that joins to a row in the main query. When you comment out Top6QtySold.list the optimizer realises it can ditch the subquery

Comment: Or in other words: Your 'OUTER APPLY' is an example of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery and they are generaly slow, especially with things like TOP and XMLPATH. You could try sticking a few indexes here or there. Ultimately for things like this I would have a temporary table that gets prepared in advance and then join to that.

Comment: Ok, I thought it doesn't matter which columns in the SELECT, joins and OUTER APPLY were always "executed"

Comment: Replace the `for xml` trick with `string_agg` (requires SQL Server 2017 or later).

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @SMor maybe you can argue a little bit... In my case, I should use it

Comment: @SalmanA Yes but I'm on compatibility level 100, going to update next week, I keep your advice